# camel return value from external Web Service

Tags: apache-camel

I need to invoke an external Web service running on WildFly from camel.
I managed to invoke it using the following route:

```
public class CamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {


final String cxfUri =
        "cxf:http://localhost:8080/DemoWS/HelloWorld?" +
        "serviceClass=" + HelloWorld.class.getName(); 
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:start")
    .id("wsClient")
    .log("${body}")
    .to(cxfUri + "&defaultOperationName=greet");


}
}
```

My question is how to get the return value from the Web service invocation ? The method used returns a String :

```
@WebService
public class HelloWorld implements Hello{

    @Override
    public String greet(String s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Hello "+s;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the service in the Wild Fly returns the value then to see the values you can do the below

public class CamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {

```
final String cxfUri =
    "cxf:http://localhost:8080/DemoWS/HelloWorld?" +
    "serviceClass=" + HelloWorld.class.getName(); 
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:start")
    .id("wsClient")
    .log("${body}")
    .to(cxfUri + "&defaultOperationName=greet").log("${body}");

//beyond this to endpoint you can as many number of componenets to manipulate the response data. 
}
}
```

The second log will log the response from the web service that you are returning. If you need to manipulate or do some routing and transformation with the response then you should look at the type of the response and accordingly you should use appropriate transformer.

Hope this helps.